# SQL Server SSIS Warning :0x80000036

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have updated my SQL Server 2008 R2 Evaluation Edition to Enterprise Edition a
couple of weeks ago. Service Pack 1 is also installed. Things were going good for a while . But when I run an SSIS package now, I get a Warning:
0x80000036: only 9 days left for evaluation.
can anyone help me out in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your upgrade didn't go through smoothly. In 9 days your message will read *"Integration Services evaluation period has expired. The package can only be executed in debug mode."*

Why not try to change the edition again via the Edition Upgrade Wizard?

There is a good thread on MS Social ([Bought SQL Server 2008 Developer Licence, How do I upgarde my Trial version with Licence version?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/5366537b-d8bc-4a05-baf9-06d870a47a1a)) suggesting to...

- Use the Edition Upgrade Wizard
- Use a command line action to upgrade 
  `Setup.exe /q /ACTION=editionupgrade /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /PID=<PID key for new edition>"`
- Contact the MS Licensing Team with questions directly (in the end you bought the product-that's what support is for ;-) )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I contacted the Microsoft team, they are advising me to go for a fresh installation, which i cannot afford to do, due to the critical nature  of the DB server. So now i'm contemplating on the command line action. If u have any other solution plz let me know. Thanks Dude! :-)

Comment: Sorry no other solution. You say the DB server is critical and you were using the evaluation version? Weird. Anyways - you could set up a "fresh" installation by just setting up another instance of the SQL server on the same machine. Then you could migrate your data to that instance and make the switch sometime later.

Comment: Consider marking the answer as the one you desire using the checkmark on the left to the answer.